# XSL - for-each not working

Tags: html, css, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have the following `XML` code (test.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="test.xsl" ?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
    <url>http://www.url.com/1/</url>
    <url>http://www.url.com/2/</url>
    <url>http://www.url.com/3/</url>
</urlset>
```

Then, I wanna give it some style with the following `XSL` code (test.xsl):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <xsl:for-each select="/urlset/url">
        <div>
            one address here (no matter which)
        </div>
    </xsl:for-each>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

For some reason there is no result, just a `blank page`.

I just followed a sample code I tried few years ago that worked for me, but this doesn't work.

Any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: It's the number #1 XSLT question here: just search for "XSLT default namespace". Someone asks it nearly every day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I just followed a sample code I tried few years ago that worked for me

The code worked a few years ago presumably because back then, your input document did not have a namespace.

Now, your input document has a *default namespace* that you need to account for in your XSLT stylesheet. Your stylesheet works if you *redeclare* this namespace in the stylesheet and *prefix* all element names coming from the input document.

I guess you probably want the following stylesheet, which outputs the contents of all `url` elements:

**XSLT Stylesheet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:stmp="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <xsl:for-each select="/stmp:urlset/stmp:url">
        <div>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </div>
    </xsl:for-each>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XHTML Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:stmp="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
      <title>Test</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div>http://www.url.com/1/</div>
      <div>http://www.url.com/2/</div>
      <div>http://www.url.com/3/</div>
   </body>
</html>
```

But your style of XSLT programming could also be improved. Instead of an unnecessary `xsl:for-each`, use `xsl:apply-templates` and write a separate template for `url` elements.

**XSLT Stylesheet (improved)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:stmp="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="stmp:url">
    <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </div>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output will be the same. Try it yourself online [here](http://xsltransform.net/bFWR5EE).

Answer (score -1):

This is a simple way of what you are trying to accomplish:

Your `XML` code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <urlset>
    <url>http://www.url.com/1/</url>  
  </urlset>
```

Your `XSLT` code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> 
 <xsl:template match="/">
  <html> 
   <body>
      <xsl:value-of select="urlset/url"/>
   </body>
  </html>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: You just moved the goal posts; the actual input document has a _namespace_ and this makes quite a difference.